# How to plot average and standard deviation together on a single graph using numpy and matplotlib in python?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Calculated mean and standard deviation of a number of 2 column text files as follow:

```
hvsr = np.array(hvsra)
hvsrm = hvsr.mean(axis=0)
hvsrstd = hvsr.std(axis=0)
```

Now, I want to plot them together that the average line and the standard deviation would be in the same figure, or at least show maximum and minimum values around the average line. Any idea please? I did the following but plots only the 1st one:

```
plt.loglog(freq, hvsrm)
plt.errorbar(freq, hvsrstd, fmt='-o')
```

Comment: also tried the following:

    plt.subplots(nrows=2, sharex=True)
    plt.loglog(freq, hvsrm)
    plt.loglog(freq, hvsrstd)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I used the `plt` syntax in the question the plot wasn't quite right. So I suggest using the `fig, ax` syntax as below. Also `errorbar` takes arguments `x, y, yerr`, so your syntax should look like below to plot mean values with std:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.loglog(freq, hvsrm)
ax.errorbar(freq, hvsrm, hvsrstd, fmt='-o')
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like `plt.vlines(hvsrm, 0, 50, linestyles ="dashed", colors ="k")`?

Comment: No, I haven't yet.